# call MainWindow.xib

Tags: iphone

I created my login screen(two field and one button) to MainWindow.xib.
After some view I want to go back to MainWindow.xib (login screen).
I really do not understand how to call MainWindow.xib again?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Snehal Mehta

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put a login screen in the MainWindow.xib. Make it live in its own view controller. Then you can simply readd that view controllers view back to the window when you deem appropriate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.The thing is that I am not able to load split view controller from view but only from window.Thats why I created login page in MainWindow.XIB.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an appropriate solution to your problem. You could load your login controller to the right hand view and load it only in portrait mode so you cant see the left one. There are other ways to deal with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call MainWindow.xib again, just close the "some view" to bring MainView visible again. Naturally this means that first you open something on top of MainView...

...so I guess the real question is how did you make that "some view" visible. Common way is using 'presentModalViewController' method. Here's quick but dirty sample code, just to give you some ideas:

Open 'about this app' dialog from main view:

```
- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{
AboutViewController *controller = [[[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

and the about view tells main view to close it:

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
[self.delegate aboutViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

and main view closes about view:

```
- (void)aboutViewControllerDidFinish:(AboutViewController *)controller
{ 
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

To make this work you define a protocol in about view header:

```
@class AboutViewController;

@protocol AboutViewControllerDelegate
- (void)aboutViewControllerDidFinish:(AboutViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface AboutViewController : UIViewController
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <AboutViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end
```

and take that into use in main view header:

```
@interface MyMainViewController : UIViewController <AboutViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

Well, I hope you got the idea and can find the rest by searching for "@protocol" and maybe even "about view sample code for iPhone" etc.